# Next.js Router.push does not set any req.headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an issue with doing backend queries in getInitialProps function after executing client side Router.push() from another endpoint.

Here is what I mean. In my signup page, I call Router.push('/') to return to the home page:

```
  proceedToIndex = () => {
    Router.push('/');
  }
```

In my '/' page, I call getInitialProps as follows:

```
  static async getInitialProps (context) {
    try {
      if (context.req.headers.cookie) {
          const resp = await getUser(context.apolloClient);

          if (resp.data.getUser && resp.data.getUser.id) {
            return { user: resp.data.getUser };
          }
      };
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    return { user: undefined };
  }
```

I end up with a crash saying cannot call cookie of undefined for context.req.headers.cookie. So headers is undefined when I execute Router.push('/'). What is going on here and how do I feed headers into my request object in context?

Comment: .Maybe [helpful](https://gist.github.com/jmurzy/f3f46e7b1807e1954321eb2ce2e83402)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no requests when using Router.push. It's a client-side API, and requests only exist in the initial server render.

Comment: This does not seem to be true anymore. A simple console.log(context.req.cookies); in getServerSideProps(context) will give you the request object with up-to-date information. However, for anyone trying to re-render the same page with new data, you should pass a key prop to your components that need to change based on the data.

Comment: @joshu getServerSideProps always runs on the server, so has access to a request. The question was about getInitialProps which runs on both server _and_ client.